# Find a conformal map between $\{z: |z - 1| < 1$ and $|z - i| < 1\}$ and the first quadrant

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to find a conformal map between the region $\{z: |z - 1| < 1$ and $|z - i| < 1\}$ and the first quadrant.  I know there are the two circles intersect at the origin and $1+i$.

My idea was to try to find a map that mapped $1+i$ to $\infty$. So I started with $T(z) = \frac{1}{z -(1+i)}$, which is conformal since it is a linear fractional transformation.

I then thought that since the two circles intersect at a 90 degree angle at the origin, the two boundaries would be mapped to lines that intersect at 90 degrees at $\frac{1}{(-1-i)}$.  I was then thinking I could rotate or translate this somehow to get that region to be the first quadrant.  However, I was having trouble figuring out what the image of the boundaries actually was.

This material is pretty new to me, so I'm not sure if I'm going about this correctly at all.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are not so far from the actual solution. Let us call the given region $\Omega$, and let $R$ stand for the first quadrant. Instead of mapping $1+i$  to $\infty$ , map $0$ to $\infty$ in a natural way, namely, consider the map $z \mapsto \frac{1}{z}$. It takes the circle $|z-1| = 1$ to the line $Re(z) = \frac{1}{2}$, and the circle $|z-i| = 1$ to the line $Im(z) = -\frac{1}{2}$. Then $\Omega$ maps to one of the 4 quadrants formed by these perpendicular lines. To locate that quadrant, just look at the image of a point inside $\Omega$, say $\frac{1+i}{2}$, which is in the region $G=\{x+iy:x>\frac{1}{2}, y<-\frac{1}{2}\}$. Rotate $G$ anti-clockwise by $90^{\circ}$, and then translate appropriately. The final mapping is, $f: \Omega \to R$ given by, 
\begin{equation}
f(z)=\frac{i}{z}-\frac{1+i}{2}.
\end{equation}